# Router navigate doesn't save url after navigate

Tags: angular, routes, angular-router

app routing:

```
  {
        path: '',
        component: IndexComponent,
        children: [
            {path: 'table', component: TimetablesStaticComponent},
            {
                path: 'comparison/:id',
                component: TimetablesAllComponent,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: 'table',
                        component: TimetablesStaticComponent,
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
```

I can navigate to table from default root: `localhost:4200/table`, and it loads TimetablesStaticComponent. But in service, i'd like to navigate to table component and save previous route. I have route `localhost:4200/comparison/123`. And from service i call method                     `this.router.navigate(['table'], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});`
And it navigates to `localhost:4200/table`, but should be `localhost:4200/comparison/123/table`
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I don't really understand your question but did you try this.router.navigate(['table/comparison/123/table'], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActivatedRoute` is different for each routed component.

Injected into `TimetablesAllComponent` it is relative to `comparison/3` and in `TimetablesStaticComponent` it is `comparison/123/table`

If you use it in service it is the root route (`""`). You need to call the navigation from the component - in your case in `TimeTablesAllComponent`. Not from the service.